# React Native RCTNetworking.sendRequest got 6 arguments, expected 7

Tags: android, react-native

I have a React Native project that I have built out for iOS and now I'd like to make it work on Android. I've followed the [setup instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html) and ran `react-native run-android` form the project root.

When it loads in the Android emulator, I get a red error screen that says:

`React Native RCTNetworking.sendRequest got 6 arguments, expected 7`

Answer (score -1):

I found this posted on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6358):

> You RN JS and Native code are out of sync. Run `react-native upgrade` in
>   your project to fix the issue.

I ran `react-native upgrade` from my project root and then `react-native run-android` again. My project loaded correctly.

Comment: This didn't work and even ended up generating new Java classes in my project, and additional risk to overwrite already written code and gradle files. This may have worked in your particular case, but is not a general solution.

Comment: This does not work. It generates a `whole new xcodeproj` I DO NOT NEED.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would create a whole new xcodeproj. It didn't do that for me; I suspect this is due to changes over time.